# Having issues while screen scraping pdf by converting to html - using ITPilot in Denodo

Tags: extractor, denodo

In ITPilot after recording the sequence, I have to screenscrape a Pdf document. I am able to convert the pdf to HTML and the resulting HTML is not totally formatted. This is resulting in the extractor in not receiving the fields exactly as needed.
Can someone help in converting the pdf to an Acrobat HTML where I am facing the problem (or) help me to screenscrape the unformatted HTML in the browser view.

Answer (score 0):

To use the function CONVERTPDFTOHTML with Adobe Acrobat the Professional version must be installed:
"ACR_HTML: configures the command to use the HTML converter of the
Adobe Acrobat Professional software (this product must be installed)."

Regarding the problem with PDFBox, maybe you are experiencing a common issue related to zoomed pages when assigning examples as described in [here](https://community.denodo.com/kb/view/document/Unable%20to%20set%20examples%20for%20PDF%20in%20ITPilot?category=ITPilot)